# Как получить записи при скроллинге?

Tags: reactjs

Получаю данные с апи, подгружаю их по 10 записей, при скролле, следующие 10 элементов не появляются...
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-chandrasekhar-mdgwe

Answer (score 0):

Судя по методу `fetchMoreListItems`, вы здорово запутались.
Если нужны будут комментарии к непонятным моментам, спрашивайте.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-driscoll-i305q

Comment: Вариант хороший, но в нем приходится крутить колесико медленно, чтобы не пропустить необходимые элементы, в моем варианте я пытался сделать как у "ВК", чтобы лента "дополняла" элементы, сохраняя при этом старые элементы